# Install third party js library mess up existing node_modules in jhipster project

Tags: npm, jhipster, npm-install

Currently I need to add third party (ng2-charts) js library to my jhipster project, open cmd window, and navigate to the application root directory, and:

```
npm install --save chart.js
npm install --save ng2-charts.js
```

After installation, I found the application is broken, some existing modules disappear, like @angular/core!

I suspect something wrong, what should be the correct way to install third party library?

Comment: Maybe you installed the wrong package? `ng2-chart.js` should be `ng2-charts`

Comment: it is a typo, updated the question.